# ubuntu xfce only ask for pw to unluck when not on private wifi

Tags: password, screen-lock

Is there any software that can make it so that my ubuntu xfce only asks for password to unluck my screen when i am not on my private wifi?

I have tried scripts but i would much prefer a legit software for something like this.